# expressjs POST response not working

Tags: jquery, post, express

Maybe it's something simple but the below code isn't working, the expressjs server is receiving the request and data, but the jQuery ajax call isn't receiving the response from the server

this is the server code

```
 app.get('/', function(req, res){
  console.log('request for /');
  res.send('hello there!');    
 });
```

this is the jQuery request

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/',
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
  });
```

this is the expressjs app configurations

```
 app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', /*process.env.PORT ||*/ 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
 });
```

EDIT: took out Json stuff, problem exists anyway

Comment: What about your extensive use of `JSON.stringify()`? This method will make a string out of a native Javascript object. I can only see the benefit of this method on server side because "data" in the client is already a string. And in success it should be `JSON.parse()`

Comment: edited, problem is existing without the JSON operations

Comment: How are you trying to make the ajax call to your express app (via curl, browser dev tool, etc.)? I'm just wondering where your javascript code is being executed since the GET request only returns "Hello there" and not any javascript. I think it could be a cross-domain issue but that's just a suspicion :)

Comment: @CraigMacGregor sticking it into an index.html file and running it in chrome, with the hope of putting it into a phonegap app

Comment: @EoinMurray so it does look like it is a cross-domain problem. You can look into using JSONP (ex. $.ajax({dataType: "JSONP"..) for this or setting the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header from the web server that is consuming this (some info: http://bionicspirit.com/blog/2011/03/24/cross-domain-requests.html). I have to head out right now, so sorry I can't be more help. Hopefully this is enough to get started.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution was to allow cross domain headers

```
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you did not end the connection in server code as below. In app.get('/', ...

```
res.end('hello there');
```

Note that **end** instead of send.